# Abrir nueva página en la misma pestaña sin perder la página actual

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, internet-explorer-11

Tengo una página en mi aplicación web, que quiero abrir desde la página principal, y que cuando ésta se cierre, se vuelva a mostrar la página principal con los datos que tenía antes, básicamente, el valor de las variables servidor y de los campos que ha rellenado el usuario.

He probado a cambiar en cada caso el location.href a la página .aspx que corresponde. También he probado con location.replace. Pero al volver en ambos casos desaparece la información, y también se ejecuta el window.onload, lo que no es aconsejable, pero eso podría controlarlo yo de alguna manera, no es lo que más me preocupa. Debe funcionar en IE 11 (creo que es un dato importante)

Answer (score 0):

Salvo que uses _blank para abrir una nueva pestaña, la unica opción que te queda es persisitir la información de la página actual de alguna manera.

Si los datos no son sensibles, podrías usar el local storage del browser (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). 
Una opción mejor es que guardes de alguna manera el estado de tu página principal con algun tipo de clave/s y con esas claves vayas a consultar al servidor para que te recargue todo el estado de la página.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [answer] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus respuestas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.